# List gcloud bucket files in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, gcloud, bucket

I would like to display the list of my google bucket storage files on my node.js app and I would like to know if it's possible or if I have to go by another way ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example I wrote in Node.js 10 for GAE standard, which you can use and adapt:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

const app = express();

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {
  let bucketName = '<BUCKET-NAME>'

  // Initiate a Storage client
  const storage = new Storage();

  // List files in the bucket and store their name in the array called 'result'
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let result = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    result.push(file.name);
  });

  // Send the result upon a successful request
  res.status(200).send(result).end();
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`);
  console.log('Press Ctrl+C to quit.');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-app",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^4.1.3"
  }
}
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs10
```

---

In order to get a list with the **URLs** instead of the file names change the following piece in the **app.js** sample provided above:

```
const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
  let result = [];
  files.forEach(file => {
    result.push("https://storage.cloud.google.com/" + bucketName + "/" + file.name);
  });
```

---

## EDIT: Getting the objects' metadata

Here is the code you can use instead in order to get the objects' metadata:

```
const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();
let result = [];
for (const file of files) {
  const [metadata] = await file.getMetadata();
  result.push(metadata.size);
};
res.status(200).send(result).end();
```

[Node.js Client Library reference](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getMetadata)

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. Then i can get metadata from files and display them as I want ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I have updated my answer adding an example. See the link I attached to explore the available attributes for metadata.

Comment: If you find this answer helpful please accept it for a better visibility within the community.